# How can I get traffic stats for a spreadsheet of URLs?

Tags: google-analytics

We are currently trying to look at the traffic to a certain category of pages on our site. The pages number into the 1000s so a manual lookup is not an option. We have managed to get the pages into a spreadsheet including their URLs.

My question is, can we query our Google Analytics data using the URLs to return a pageview metric for each URL (ideally within a given date range)? I have played around with Google Sheets and the Analytics plugin, but didn't get anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do the pages have something in common (part of the url, page title etc) ? If you do not have something you can filter by you need to query per Url which means you will, with 1000s of urls, rather quickly exceed your API quota. You might consider creating a content grouping and use that as a filter (will not work for data that's already been collected).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Eike, I had not thought of the API quota. Luckily I have managed to hack away at the issue myself and come up with a solution by exporting traffic data into Excel and doing a lookup on the page URL. Thanks again for you comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this which was to go back to good old fashioned Excel.

I exported the pageview data from analytics as a spreadsheet and used this to do a lookup using my list of URLs. Worked a treat, so hope this helps anyone else with this problem.